# angularjs tree directive with filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

Good day. I made a [tree directive with filter](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/6BorEN9Tht5bezmkfys9/).
I want to see tree-node if its name or child name contains word.
So, everything works when I filter data in controller:

```
$scope.data1 = $filter('treeName')($scope.data, $scope.name);
<tree model="data1"/>
```

But when I add my filter **| treeName: name** in model expression

```
<tree model="data | treeName: name"/>
```

Angular cause a lot of exceptions on interaction

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22m…r%20e%3Da(c%2Cd)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A1%7D%5D%5D
```

Also setSelected never called.
What am I doing wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/6BorEN9Tht5bezmkfys9?p=preview

Comment: <tree model="data1 | treeName: name"></tree>

Comment: @Reena, data1 is data filtered in changeFilter.